# Can I autowire a proptotype bean in a singelton bean directly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was viewing some legacy code and found that here is a singelton bean say X and I have autowire a prototype bean in it like:

```
@Controller
public class X {
  @Autowired
  private Y y;
  // ....
}
```

And Y is defined as:

```
@Component
@scope("prototype")
public class Y {

}
```

Now as per my understanding to inject a prototype bean in a singelton bean we have two approach

1. scoped Proxy
2. method injection

Now in the above code none of the above mentioned approach is used. So shall I believe that although a prototype bean is injected in class X but still it will behave as singelton bean that is only single instance of Y will be available inside X class  throughout the application scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A prototype bean creates new instance every time you get it from the context.
In this situation Spring creates the singleton(the class X) ant then gets bean of type Y from the context to inject it in X. This will happen only one time for the lifetime of the application. So the instance of Y that is injected in X will live as long as X.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if there's no proxying (lookup method injection), X will have a single instance of Y which will not change between invocations of X's methods (an instance of Y is created and autowired into X when X is being constructed by the application context). If another class Z were to autowire Y into itself, it would also get its own instance (not shared with X). because Y is declared as a prototype (each time an instance of Y is requested from the application context, a new instance will be created).

For more information, see for example Spring IoC container documentation 5.5.2 and 5.5.3 : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype